# Number of natural numbers when multiplied having 1000 divisors

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

All natural numbers are coloured using $100$ different colours. Prove that one can find several (no less than 2) different numbers, all of the same colour, that have a product with exactly $1000$ different natural divisors.

I do not know how to start. Pls help.

Comment: Just use the pidgeonhole principle: there are certainly more than 100 numbers with exactly 1000 different natural divisors  (any $p^{999}$ for $p$ prime).

Comment: @Dzoooks The question asks for two numbers whose product has exactly $1000$ divisors. It is not just about one number.

Comment: that's one form of number not just one number. Also there's no less than 34 forms to get 1000 divisors. okay miscounted 17, forgot about a factor of 1 not counting.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: my hand count gives $22$ and I might have missed some. The exponents on the primes are $(1,1,1,4,4,4),(1,3,4,4,4),(7,4,4,4),(1,1,1,4,24),(1,3,4,24),(7,4,24),(1,1,1,124),(1,3,124),(7,124),(1,1,4,4,9),(3,4,4,9),(1,1,9,24),(3,9,24),(1,4,4,19),(1,4,9,9),(9,9,9),(9,99),(999),(1,4,99),(1,19,24),(1,499),(4,199)$

Comment: I used forsubset on the divisors of 1000 and got 34 originally, but most had a factor of 1 hidden in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers of the form $p^9q^9r^9$ with $p,q,r$ different primes have $1000$ factors.  At least one of the colors has infinitely many numbers of the form $p^9$ of that color.  You can then select any three of those and multiply them together to get a number with $1000$ factors.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be a prime number.  Observe that $p^{999}$ has exactly 1000 divisors.  Note that there are infinitely many primes.  If all natural numbers are colored with any finite number of colors, then by the pidgeonhole principle there are at least two (in fact, infinitely many) prime powers $p_1^{999}$ and $p_2^{999}$ that are colored the same.

Comment: and same extends to the powers making them up, which is why they say product.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  We are not asked for two numbers with $1000$ divisors that are the same color, but for a collection of numbers, all of which are the same color, that multiply to a product with $1000$ divisors.  If you could find primes $p,q$ such that $p$ and $q^{499}$ were the same color you would have a solution.  It won't be that simple, because we could color the first power of all primes with one color and the $499^{th}$ power of all primes some other color.

Comment: I agree with ross